Long Applescript causing crash with segmentation fault
I have an Applescript script that I run as a batch against a photo editing app (Capture One). It is auto-generated by another app and creates smart collections out of a database of keywords. It is quite long and over time becomes longer and longer because more keywords are added from time to time. At the moment it's about 50k lines and 5MB long. It's quite slow to run (several hours), but this is another matter (in any case I run it overnight a few times per year). I've been running it without problems since a couple of years.
The script is basically an unrolled loop of about 3.600 iterations, each one does basically the same things over different data. It has grown quite a bit recently because I added a few lines to compute estimated completion time. Now it seems it never completes, because at a certain point (more or less 2/3 of the script, not always at the same point) a few strange error messages are printed on the console (an excerpt here):
Catalog 2024-11-23T00:57:01.192162Capture One got an error: Can’t make document into type integer.4-1700
make
group, Capture One got an error: Can’t make progress total units into type text., name, -1700
Catalog 2024-11-23T00:57:01.192162
«class prdt», Capture One got an error: Can’t make make into type text., kind, -1700
group


and shortly after a segmentation fault occurs. I believe there's some sort of memory corruption, so the console output is meaningless. Inspecting the block of code where the script crashes shows no issues, and if I run the same script again the crash might happen a bit earlier or later, so I the code is not relevant.
The script is run by command line with osascript.
Is there any limitation to the lenght of an Applescript? Ideas? Workarounds? I anticipate that splitting the script or resuming from the point it stopped is not an easy option for me, for a number of reasons related to Capture One APIs.
Thanks.
PS I've said I don't think code is relevant, anyway this is an iteration:
    try
      set progress text to "Importing: Workflow/workflow:published/workflow:published#twitter-weekly"
      tell _workflow_published to make collection with properties {kind:smart album, name:"workflow:published#twitter-weekly", rules:"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><MatchOperator Kind=\"AND\"><Condition Enabled=\"YES\"><Key>IB_S_CONTENT_KEYWORDS</Key><Operator>6</Operator><Criterion>workflow:published#twitter-weekly</Criterion></Condition></MatchOperator>"}
      set progress completed units to 3670
      set ___elapsedtime to (current date) - ___basetime
      set ___ct to ___elapsedtime * 0.000272
      set ___completionTime to "" & (___ct div 60) & " minutes to complete"
      set ___eta to  time string of ((current date) + ___ct)
      set progress additional text to "3670 / 3671 — 99% " & ___completionTime & " " & ___eta & ""
    on error errorMessage number errorNumber
      log "errorMessage: " & errorMessage & ", errorNumber: " & errorNumber
      log ">>>> keyword: Workflow/workflow:published/workflow:published#twitter-weekly"
    end try


I hope someone else has experience with this. This is the sort of thing when a change is made, sometimes we kept an old Mac on the previous stable version to let heavyweight code that’s somehow very stable stay running. You might need to track which OS updates came along since this was last stable and try that to rule out an error on your scripting change updates.

I'm not aware of a length limitation for scripts, although 50000 lines seems a bit excessive.  Long scripts are really hard to debug, especially if it is just big chunks of code with minimal use of handlers.  Is there an issue with using a (smaller) common script and passing the individual data sets to it instead of duplicating the functionality 3600 times?

As I mentioned, the script is auto-generated, so there's no need to debugging it: the logics are elsewhere and the generator code is well tested. Having a smaller Applescript code managing a data structure would definitely be a problem, since the generator code is expected to grow by manipulating semantic data structures using libraries that in Applescript are not available. There could be a trade off making most of the computation externally, but I don't see why I should make things more complex than needed.
